# Facebook Graph API 2 - type of user ids when storing in database

Tags: mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any good pattern to store users `_id` on a database using Facebook Graph Api 2?

I have 2 options here

1. Bigint
2. Varchar

Also if i use `varchar` how long must it be? 64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** use varchar(255)

**Long answer:**

Facebook states that you should not make any assumptions about the structure of IDs returned from their APIs:

> We specifically do not document any node/object ID structure or format because  it is extremely likely to change over time and apps should not make assumptions  based on current structure.

[source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview#objectids)

In the marketing API docs, it says:

> Each id returned in that API call should be considered opaque [...]

[source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/chapter-3-ad-creative#creatives)

Facebook's [Simon Cross](https://www.facebook.com/sicross) states the following in the [Facebook Developer Community group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/):

> We don't have immediate plans to change to alphanumeric uids, but you MUST ensure you're storing them as bigints at the very least. Varchar 255 is the ideal format.

[permalink](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/853874004656115/?comment_id=853916547985194)